# How do I get appended text to start at the bottom of a TextBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox, chat

I want the first line of text to be displayed visually at the bottom of the TextBox instead of at the top, is this possible? I don't want to start by padding out with carriage returns before appending the first line, I am hoping there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
VerticalAlignment= "bottom"
```

That should align the text to start at the bottom of the text box. I don't know what will happen when your input exceeds the length of the box.

Comment: Yes VerticalContentAlignment was actually what I was after in my case but that helped me find it.